# How to send 2 newsletter success emails at the same time with magento

Tags: magento-1.8, email, newsletter

I managed to add the 2nd emails select field but am wondering how to send 2 different emails to the newsletter subscriber.

[image]

Comment: Out of the box Magento will only send one subscription success email. That said you can always include your voucher in the transactional email. To send a second email will require additional modifications.

Comment: Hi Eirik, thanks for your reply. Do you know how to customize the additional email?

Comment: you have now duplicated your original question 4 times, please avoid doing this, people will answer your question if they have an answer, spamming the forums with the same question multiple time is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Magento allows to send only one success email template by default. We can set this success email template via

```
System  >  Configuration  > Newsletter  >  Success Email Template
```

You can see that, it uses a **dropdown** section. This allows us to set only one email template for success mail. So you need to change this section to **multiselct**, so that you can select multiple success email templates. You again need to rewrite `Mage_Newsletter`'s `Subscriber`  model class in order to send multiple mails at a time.

So let us create a custom module, that do this for us. I love to call this module as `Rkt_TwoNlSuccess`.

**Activation file of the module**

File : `app\etc\modules\Rkt_TwoNlSuccess.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rkt_TwoNlSuccess>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Newsletter />
            </depends>
        </Rkt_TwoNlSuccess>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Note our module depends upon `Mage_Newletter` module. It is necessary.

**System.xml file**

This file defines system configuration definitions and alternation. We use this file to make success email template field multiselect instead of select.

File : `app\code\local\Rkt\TwoNlSuccess\etc\system.xml`

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <newsletter>
            <groups>
                <subscription>
                    <fields>
                        <success_email_template>
                            <label>Success Email Template</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </success_email_template>
                    </fields>
                </subscription>
            </groups>
        </newsletter>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Note we changed front type.

```
<frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
```

So our first part is over. Now its time to do model rewrite

**Rewrite Model file**

We need to rewrite `sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()` method that is defined in the model class `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber`. This is important since the default code allows us to send only one mail. In order to do that you need to define two files.

File : `app\code\local\Rkt\TwoNlSuccess\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rkt_Freepro>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Rkt_Freepro>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <newsletter>
                <rewrite>
                    <subscriber>Rkt_TwoNlSuccess_Model_Subscriber</subscriber>
                </rewrite>
            </newsletter>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

This file just tells magento that, I need to rewrite the class `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber` with my custom class `Rkt_TwoNlsuccess_Model_Subscriber`. So magento will process this custom model class instead of default one. This is the great flexibility that Magento offers.

File :  `app\code\local\Rkt\TwoNlSuccess\Model\Subscriber.php`

```
<?php
class Rkt_TwoNlSuccess_Model_Subscriber extends Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
{
    const XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE       = 'newsletter/subscription/success_email_template';
    const XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY       = 'newsletter/subscription/success_email_identity';

    public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
    {
        if ($this->getImportMode()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if(!Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE)
           || !Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY)
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

        $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $email_templates = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE));
        $identity = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY);

        foreach ($email_templates as $template) {
            $email->sendTransactional(
                $template,
                $identity,
                $this->getEmail(),
                $this->getName(),
                array('subscriber'=>$this)
            );
        }


        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Here we are rewriting the method `sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()`. The following code that does the trick here

```
        $email_templates = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE);
        $identity = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY);

        foreach ($email_templates as $template) {
            $email->sendTransactional(
                $template,
                $identity,
                $this->getEmail(),
                $this->getName(),
                array('subscriber'=>$this)
            );
        }
```

This code allows you to send any number of emails. So now you can send more than two success emails if you desire.

### EDIT

You set `need confirm` to `YES`. That is what actually making problem here. If that values is set, then Magento will send success mails to only logged in customers who are trying to subscribe newsletter. For guest users, it will always send confirm mail.

In order to send success mail for all users, you need to set `need confirm` to `NO`.

Please note, there is a minor bug in my `subscriber.php` file. I have fixed it and tested it. It works in local server. I have updated that code here. So save this updated code inside `app/code/local/Rkt/TwoNlSuccess/Model/Subscriber.php`.

Let me know whether it solves your problem.

Hope that will help

Comment: the multiselect doesn't work..hmmm

Comment: @chris_magento : didn't get you. what is the problem that you facing ?

Comment: I am getting this error when I click on the verification link in the email http://www.dev1.jeoeljewelry.com/2ndsuccessemail1.jpg.   Any ideas?

Comment: this is not what my code does. My code allow you to add multiple success email template at a time instead of adding an extra field in newsletter configuration section

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Initially I set as multiselect but it doesn't work so i change it to select...Have a look     dev1.jeoeljewelry.com/multiselect.jpg  Appreciate your help ...

Comment: that is because you need to rewrite the `subscriber.php` file as I described in my answer. Once you do that, I hope it will work for sure

Comment: in the subscriber.php, my class "Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract". Should I change it to "class Rkt_TwoNlSuccess_Model_Subscriber extends Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber" instead

Comment: no DONT EDIT CORE FILES. Read my answer fully. It gives you a module in effect. You need to create those files manually.

Comment: Sorry buddy for the troubles.I am pretty new to magento so in need of help..I have created and added the the file to app\etc\modules\Rkt_TwoNlSuccess.xml . Also I have created files and folders in app\code\local\Rkt\TwoNlSuccess\etc\ and app\code\local\Rkt\TwoNlSuccess\Model like the image shown  http://dev1.jeoeljewelry.com/filesfolder.jpg . I can receive 1st confirmation email  but I don't receive any of the success emails. Do you know what have I done wrong?...

Comment: when should you get success messages ? you have done everything correctly. I appeciate your effort\

Comment: did you select 2 success email templates in backend for your site and then saved the configuration ?

Comment: Visitor should get the 2 success messages after confirmation. Having said that visitor signup--> receive confirmation email -> click on the confirmation link -> visitor receive 2 success emails (eg: thankyou and voucher). The confirmation email is working perfectly fine. The problem here is i cannot receive the success emails..

Comment: ya got the situation perfectly. and what about my second question. did you set two email templates for success mail field in `system  >  configuration  > newsletter` ?

Comment: Yes buddy. I did. Here you go www.dev1.jeoeljewelry.com/select.jpg

Comment: ok let me inspect again. I will update you soon

Comment: take a look now. It will solve all issues

Comment: wow! i got all the mails haha..but what about the confirmation mail? Need them to verify like before....Thanks a lot. You are great !

Comment: you need to confirm mail before send success mail right ? that one is not fitting here. You need to put it as new question. Because it involves some alterations. Any ways accept this as answer for this question and come with next question. In addition to that, I need to suggest you that, don't repeat the same question again and again here

Comment: well noted. Thanks a lot buddy!!!! you are the best. You have solve part of my problems!

Comment: yes accept this as right answer so that future visitors get benefited from your own question

Comment: oookiee! :-) Thanks again...Sorry for repeating the questions and will not do it again...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

This is actually an option by default in Magento configuration! Go to `System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails`

[image]

Enter a secondary address to CC/BCC

Comment: Misunderstood the reasoning for the question but will leave this here so others don't misunderstand, too. Feel free to downvote!

Comment: he he. I love it. you rocks @philwinkle :)

Comment: have a look on my answer. He posted the same question 4 times here. So I decided to "react". That is what this answer. NOte: I am not critisizing him. I can understand his feeling :)