# send 2 success newsletter email in magento. Any ideas?

Tags: magento-1.7, email, newsletter

I am looking for is the subscription newsletter section. As you can see, there is only one success email template. I need to send 2 emails. Do you know which files handling the email section so I can customize....Your answer will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to customise admin to add a setting for a second email template or how to customise the email sending process to send a second email (or both)?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, sorry for the confusion. The first one - adding a setting for a second email template. Any ideas? Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are already familiar with module development, it's pretty straightforward to add extra settings under the `system -> configuration` section of admin, and to extend/edit settings added by core modules you just need to add the equivalent node structure into the `system.xml` file of your own module.  Because your module will always load after all core modules the settings you define will take precedence.

In this case if you search the codebase, you will see the above settings are added by the newsletter core module `system.xml` at `app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/etc/system.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <newsletter translate="label" module="newsletter">
            ...
            <groups>
                <subscription translate="label">
                    ...
                    <fields>
                        ...
                        <success_email_template translate="label">
                            <label>Success Email Template</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </success_email_template>
                        ...
                    </fields>
                </subscription>
            </groups>
        </newsletter>
    </sections>
</config>
```

To extend this and add your own additional email template just mirror the same structure in your `system.xml` adding an additional dropdown setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <newsletter>
            <groups>
                <subscription>
                    <fields>
                        <another_success_email_template translate="label">
                            <label>Another Success Email Template</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </another_success_email_template>
                    </fields>
                </subscription>
            </groups>
        </newsletter>
    </sections>
</config>
```

You will then be able to pull the setting you select here with:

```
$template = Mage::getStoreConfig('newsletter/subscription/another_success_email_template');
```

The only thing to note here is that it appears the sort order of the settings is set to `1` for every setting in the core `system.xml` so you might have trouble getting the order set correctly for your new setting, however you could redefine the sort order for the existing settings if you wanted also in your new `system.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <newsletter>
            <groups>
                <subscription>
                    <fields>
                        <success_email_template>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </success_email_template>
                        <another_success_email_template translate="label">
                            <label>Another Success Email Template</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </another_success_email_template>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        </un_email_identity>
                        ...
                    </fields>
                </subscription>
            </groups>
        </newsletter>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan! Let me try the if the code is working. thank you sooo much! ..Please don't go, hope you will be here in case im stuck....

Comment: Hi Jonathan, mind to share which file is pointing to this  $template = Mage::getStoreConfig('newsletter/subscription/another_success_email_template');

Comment: That's the line you need to use in order to pull the extra template setting - use it wherever you are sending the extra success email to define the template to use.  Have a look at my answer [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35452/var-store-getfrontendname-returns-nothing-in-email-templates/35458#35458) for a very quick run through of sending transactional emails.

Comment: @JonathanHussey : this is also a good solution. But rather than this my approach would be more correct. What's your thought on that ? +1 for this answer

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to insert a link with your comment?

Comment: @JonathanHussey :http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35499/how-to-send-2-newsletter-success-emails-at-the-same-time-with-magento/ this is the link. Have a look

Comment: Yeah worth having the link there for future reference, I only covered adding the admin setting as that is all that was asked for.