# which file contatin this $template = Mage::getStoreConfig('newsletter/subscription/success_email_template'); in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, email, newsletter

I am just wondering where can I find this file

```
$template = Mage::getStoreConfig('newsletter/subscription/success_email_template');
```

in Magento?

I need to add another line but I could not find the file
`$template = Mage::getStoreConfig('newsletter/subscription/another_success_email_template');`

Appreciate your answer.....

Comment: chris_magento, please stick to your original question thread rather than starting 3 questions just to try and get an answer...

Answer (score 0):

**The method `getStoreConfig()` will return system configuration values based on the path specified.**

It holds two parameters. First one is **path** and second one is **store**. So in this case, it will return the value that is specified at

```
 System  >  Configuration  > Newsletter  >  Success Email Template
```

Since it does not pass store value, it will return value under the `default configuration scope` value

Comment: what about the backend code. I am customizing a second success email and I need to add the above code so I can use it to send email.

Comment: this answer gives you complete details of what you have asked here. you can accept this, if it resolved your doubt. I have answered on your original post. Have look on that http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35499/how-to-send-2-newsletter-success-emails-at-the-same-time-with-magento/

Answer (score 0):

You can set your another email at file :

```
app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php
```

function

public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
    {

```
    $email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this)
    );
```

**add Following code for new email**

```
    $email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(''newsletter/subscription/another_success_email_template''),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this)
    );
}
```

This is for frontend customer subscribe to newsletter i am not sure that the same used for when admin edits the customer. I am still searching from where it send mail.